# Is this a valid sentence using "approbation"

Tags: meaning, sentence

I believe the word means to approve or praise. So can I use it as

> Are you looking for an approbation from your boss ?

or

> Why are you still standing here ? Do you want me to approbate you  ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let's start from the first sentence you indicate.

**Approbation** is an uncountable noun which corresponds to the perhaps more frequently used ***approval***, so you can ask *"Are you looking for your boss's **approbation**?"*

The verb ***to approbate*** on the contrary is less frequent (the OED for example does not list it). You can find it with the meaning of *"To sanction officially; authorize"* in The American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language, Fourth Edition; it is used with the meaning of  *"to accept as valid"* in Scottish Law; it is listed in Wiktionary with the meaning of *"To give official sanction, consent or authorization"*. To sum up, therefore, I think that the verb is not appropriately used in your second sentence because it has a rather more formal connotation than necessary, and I would replace it with ***"to approve (of)"***.

Comment: Being of too-formal [register](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/register) (sense 11) does not make usage *incorrect*; it may make it *inappropriate*.

Comment: @jwpat7. You are right, this way the meaning is clearer, although according to the OED *appropriate* means *suitable, acceptable or correct for the particular circumstances*. I'll edit my post as you suggest. Thank you.

Comment: @Paola +1. I continue to appreciate, even with a bit of wonder, your excellent English language skills. (p.s.: competing with jwpat7 is rather difficult; s/he is the best here.)

Comment: @Carlo_R. You flatter me, Carlo. I keep visiting this site because I don't consider myself such a competent English speaker and I always find something new to learn. Your progress over the past few months is surely more impressive.

Answer (score 4):

I would say that those two sentences are technically correct.  However, I've always found the word to sound clunky at the best of times, so I rarely use or enjoy it.

If I were to change anything, I might drop the "an" from your first sentence.

Comment: Do you mean that approbation is a mass noun?